# Create a pdf from which images cannot be extracted

Tags: pdf, images, libreoffice

I would like to make a PDF (of a Libre-Office document) that has the following properties:

- The images it contains cannot be extracted and saved;
- It contains hyperlinks that should be keep on working.

Questions:

- Is there a Linux tool that allows to have these two features in a PDF document?
- Or just one that allows to flatten both features on the background, so that the viewer is not presented with an opportunity to save the image from the document by hovering over it with the mouse?

If so, suggestion on how to do this are gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to PDF format document creation, not to UNIX in any shape or form.

Comment: If "zooming to 400% and taking a screenshot" is extracting, you're out of luck. Unfortunately, some of the protection settings in PDFs are mere flags that the display program might choose to ignore, so disabling copy/paste is a mere annoyance and not a protection.

Comment: @MelBurslan This appears to be a question about how to use a Unix/Linux application (LibreOffice, or some post-processing tools), which per the help center is on-topic.

Comment: This is off topic. Yet, you can set password for protection

Comment: There are more PDF experts on StackOverflow than here (I suspect the answer is that you can't restrict image extraction without using a server-based content protection tool).

Comment: Is the best place for this [SO] or [SU]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "cannot".

PDF includes a password-protection system which features permissions, and you can (for example) allow viewing only. You can set these permissions using `pdftk`'s `allow` option, for example. Or, actually, in the "Security" tab of LibreOffice's "Export as PDF..."

[image: LibreOffice PDF Options dialog showing Security tab]

But the permissions are enforced by the PDF viewer—Adobe Acrobat will surely pay attention to them, but other tools may not. For example, Okular has a checkbox to turn it on or off ("obey DRM restrictions").

If by "cannot" you mean to actually make it impossible, then no. Worst case, someone could always take a picture of the screen with a camera.

Comment: I appreciate the point of the screen snapshot. However think of a headed paper with a logo that you want to make it a bit hard to save out (e.g. no right click on the object and 'save as'...). I have tried the suggested LibreOffice settings and evince seems to be completely insouciant to them. Also Adobe, as it is set, doesn't do differently from a previous PDF with no permissions. Therefore, I take that the answer is 'mostly no'.

Comment: @XavierStuvw with the permissions set, Adobe Acrobat shouldn't let you. Not sure about Evince.

Comment: I would best describe my experience that Adobe didn't let me also without permissions set -- in a narrow sense though: I only mean that hovering over the image with the pointer and right clicking does not offer a chance to save the image (then I could resort to the snapshot tool if I want). I am aware that there are tools (pdfmod, I believe) that can extract all images of a PDF document -- it would be interesting if this can be impeded.